# how do i align logo Header and Paragraph in jumbotron in dash bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I am using Dash in python, I am trying to align the logo header and paragraph in the same horizontal level in a jumbotron but it is not working for me. I am getting something like this.
[image]

But I want to make it look like the image below
[image]

I am using these external style sheets

```
external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP,'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
```

this is the code for the layout I tried to implement

```
html.A(
            
            dbc.Jumbotron(
                [

                    dbc.Col( html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()),style={'height':'100px',
                                                                                                  'align':'center'})),

                    dbc.Col( html.H1(children='header',
                      style={
                          'text-align':'center',
                          'color':'white'
                      }
                      )),
                        dbc.Col(html.P(children='version',
                           style={
                               'text-align':'right',
                                'color':'white'
                           })),
                ],
                style={
                    'height':'auto',
                    'width':'auto',
                    'background-color':'#0067b9',
                }
    ),
    )
```

any help would of great help to me Thank you.

latest change in code :

```
html.A(
            # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
            dbc.Jumbotron(
                [

                    dbc.Col( html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()),style={'height':'100px',
                                                                                                  'width':'15%',
                                                                                                  'align':'left'})),

                    dbc.Col( html.H1(children='Header',
                      style={
                          'text-align':'center',
                          'color':'white'
                      }
                      )),
                        dbc.Col(html.H6(children='version',
                           style={
                               'text-align':'right',
                                'color':'white'
                           })),
                ],
                style={
                    'height':'auto',
                    'width':'auto',
                    'text-align':'left',
                    'background-color':'#0067b9',
                    'align-items': 'center'
                }
    ),
    )
```

here is the result
[image]

after adding `display:flex`
[image]

Comment: Use `flexbox` by giving `align-items: center` to the parent.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried this way but it's the same no change.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the dom after styles applied

Comment: please check the question I updated it over there.

Comment: I mean, add a screenshot of the elements, once you take the inspect element and etc

Comment: can you confirm if it is the one I added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234842/discussion-between-rohith-santosh-and-abin-thaha).

Comment: Also try adding `display: flex` in addition to `align-items: center` to the parent

Comment: hi after adding `display:  flex` it totally moved toward  left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html.A(
            # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
            dbc.Row(
                [

                    dbc.Col( html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()),style={'height':'100px',
                                                                                                  'width':'15%',
                                                                                                  'align':'left'})),

                    dbc.Col( html.H1(children='Header',
                      style={
                          'text-align':'center',
                          'color':'white'
                      }
                      )),
                        dbc.Col(html.H6(children='version',
                           style={
                               'text-align':'right',
                                'color':'white'
                           })),
                ],
                style={
                    'height':'auto',
                    'width':'auto',
                    'text-align':'left',
                    'background-color':'#0067b9',
                    'align-items': 'center'
                }
    ),
    )
```